# Is Naive Bayes suitable for large datasets with thousands of features?

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes, large-data

I have a data set with 100 million rows and 15,000 categorical variables each with 0/1 values. My target variable is also a 0/1 binary variable. Is Naive Bayes suitable in terms of computational performance, and prediction? The main concern is the number of explanatory variables which may limit performance which is why I am not using random forests and SVMs.

Answer (score 1):

Naive Bayes is only as suitable as the results are useful. It's called "naive" for a reason, since it makes strong assumptions, but it's also very popular and performs surprisingly well in a variety of situations. It's hard to say more without more details about your use case.

As for speed, naive Bayes classifiers are fitted in $O(np)$ time , where $n$ is the number of observations and $p$ is the number of features. Again, it's hard to say if that's *good* without more details. But it's a lot better than a support vector machine.

You might want to consider Vowpal Wabbit, a learning algorithm that is "able to learn from terafeature datasets with ease." It is designed to run very fast in parallel. You can read more about it [here](http://hunch.net/~vw/).

Answer (score 1):

People use naive bayes on textual features all the time. The text features can be single words or pairs of words. Depending on the size of the vocabulary the number of features in these cases is many more than 15,000. Given that, it is entirely appropriate to use naive bayes on datasets with 100 million rows and 15,000 features.